# Positions of buttons change after being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi, I made a leftmenu that hides on a button click and shows on another button's click. When I click the ".smaller" button, the leftmenu's width changes to 0px and the ".bigger" button appears. But when I click this button somehow the position of the ".smaller" button is changed to another location.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="header">

            </div>

            <div id="leftmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ideas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="smaller"></div>
                <div class="bigger"></div>
            </div><!--leftmenu end-->

                    <div id="content">

                    </div>
        </div><!--container end-->      

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
}

html{
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
}

#leftmenu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #b99d84;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-out;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftmenu:hover{
    transition: .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in;
    background: #a2805e;
}

#leftmenu ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#leftmenu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#leftmenu ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#leftmenu ul li a:hover{
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px white;    
}

.smaller{
    position: fixed;
    top: 22%;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 120px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid white;
    opacity: .75;
    border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-out;
}

.bigger{
    position: fixed;
    top: 22%;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 120px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;
    display: none;
}

#content{
width: 60%;
height: 100%;
background: #d7d7d7;
margin: 0 20%;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
border-right: 1px solid gray;
 }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".smaller").click(function(){
        $("#leftmenu").css("width", "0px");

        $("#leftmenu ul").fadeOut();
        $(".smaller").hide();
        $(".bigger").show();

       //content widths and margins
        $("#content").css("width", "80%");
        $(this).css("width", "80%");

        $("#content").css("margin", "0 auto");
        $(this).css("margin", "0 auto");
    });//smaller.click end

    $(".bigger").click(function(){

        $(".bigger").hide();    
        $(".smaller").show();

        $("#leftmenu").css("width", "200px");
        $("#leftmenu ul").fadeIn();

    });//bigger.click end   


    $("#content").css("width", "60%");
    $(this).css("width", "60%");

    $("#content").css("margin", "0 20%");
    $(this).css("margin", "0 20%");
```

});

Thanks a lot, if anybody could find the answer, I've been stuck on this for a long time..

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, but could you post a fiddle? It makes it a little easier when dealing with layouts and this much code. =)

Comment: Well the menu is pretty much the only thing on the page right now thats what I've been working on now, but I'll remove some components like the content div and its attached jquery functions :)

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply, I added a top:0; and a left:0; to my leftmenu style and still got exactly the same problem :/

Comment: your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/S7TW3/, do you have a live page were we can see your problem?

Comment: LOL? The position of the arrows really change on my screen after both of them are pressed ones (the ".smaller" button and ".bigger" button)... this is really weird sure you did nothing to the code to fix this?

Comment: Straight copy from your question. Maybe you have other code running that could be doing it? Other js/css libraries loaded?

Comment: Yeah I removed some thing's to make the code shorter, srry (Kind of a newbie to this) I'll put it back and then you'll notice it wait a sec pls

Comment: No answers anymore? Pls help people I am still stuck on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Line 12 in your javascript change `$(this).css("width", "80%");` to `$(this).css("width", "0%");`.